# Sonarqube flagging project as test project

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0

Using sonarqube 5.0.1 with Sonar-Runner and Dotcover.
I have a project that has the substring "test" in its path, however it is not a test project.

I can see the following entry in run output:
"Adding the Visual Studio test project: ****.*****.Testing.********." (Reducted some of the name) - So looks like its flagging this project as a test project.
Also, the path for the project contains that substring:
 F:...\workspaces\***-Testing-****-1\Src\Testing.*****\****.***.Testing.****\****.****.Testing.*****.csproj

I am using the following pattern for test projects:

sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Tests

Not sure why this is getting flagged. - I also tried using the below regex:
sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=[^\\]*Test[^\\]*$

According to following bug:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-121

Please advise why this is getting flagged as test project and how can I go around this.

In sonarqube - coverage is being displayed, but no lines of code, no issues.

**Edit**

Full command from Jenkins:
(reducted some internal data with *):

E:....\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.com ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarhost.com:9000 ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=F:...\workspaces\jenkinsjob -1 -Dsonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=reports\nunit-result.xml -Dsonar.resharper.solutionFile=Src\Testing.***\Testing.***.sln -Dsonar.resharper.projectName=***.***.Testing.**** -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=Src\Testing.****\Testing.****.sln -Dsonar.fxcop.mode=skip -Dsonar.exclusions=*.Designer.cs -Dsonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Tests -Dsonar.language=cs -Dsonar.visualstudio.enable=true -Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=reports\coverage-report.html -Dsonar.resharper.installDirectory=E:....\ReSharperCommandLineTools09Update1 -Dsonar.projectVersion=2.1 -Dsonar.dotnet.fxcop=skip -Dsonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt=true -Dsonar.projectName=****.****.Testing.***** -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=company.com:***.**.Testing.***** -Dsonar.scm.disabled=true -Dsonar.dotnet.key.generation.strategy=safe

Comment: Are you calling the Java sonar-runner directly, or are you using the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner? (The bug SONARMSBRU-121 that you refer to above relates specifically to the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner).

If you are using the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner then you should set the property "sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern" for C# projects and sonar.vb.msbuild.testProjectPattern for VB projects.

sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern is used by the now-obsolete Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am calling Sonar-Runner via jenkins directly (sonar plugin)

Please see the edit above - I will add the full command thats being sent